# Angular ng-show with functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am designing an menu order system with angular allowing people to have multiple quantities of the same order. I have an issue while using ng-show. From my understanding ng-show keeps track of provided expression, but in my case it seems to only evaluate it once. Below is my code.

**View**

```
<a ng-click="menu.addMenuItem(category.items[$index])"> <span class="plus glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
<span ng-show="{{menu.getItemQuantity(category.items[$index])}}">
    {{menu.getItemQuantity(category.items[$index])}}
    <a ng-click="menu.subMenuItem(category.items[$index])"> <span class="minus glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></a>
</span>
```

**Controller**

```
var vm=this;
vm.getItemQuantity = function(item){
    return shoppingCart.getItemQuantity(item);//refers to service function
}
```

**service**

```
var getItemQuantity = function(item){
    var inOrder = isItemInOrder(item); //custom function

    if(inOrder.check){
        return cart.order[inOrder.index].quantity;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The objective of this code is to get the span element in the view to be toggled to show up after the customer has selected the menu item to be included. Currently, when an item is added to the view, the entire application registers it. Event the function in the ng-show also returns the proper answer, but for some reason it does not automatically keep toglling. It only seems to be evaluating my expression once. What gives?

Comment: what is it currently doing? does it stay open? or does it close and not re-open?

Comment: Have you tried putting a function in your ngShow instead and returning something like a watcher on the data?

Comment: ng-show evaluates if something is truthy or falsy. in your code your show is calling the `getItemQuantity()` and passing it a value that is resulting in it returning a truthy result. Now it has it's value and will not re-evaluate. It does not automatically toggle. You can either save and then reset the value, or perhaps set up a toggle function similar to this: http://geniuscarrier.com/ng-toggle-in-angularjs/

Comment: @HolyMoly Thank you for your answer. I dont think that will work for me since I am actually looping through an array of food items and what I am displaying above actually within my ng-repeat. Do you have more suggestions

Comment: @JudsonTerrell What do you mean? I am relatively new to angular

Comment: if you put this on a page, what does it show as you add items etc {{menu.getItemQuantity(category.items[$index])}}

Comment: i think the problem is that ng-show relies on something returning true or false. So you might want to say something like {{menu.getItemQuantity(category.items[$index])}} > 0 or something like that.

Comment: @JudsonTerrell it returns the number 0

Comment: let me try to see if that works

Comment: so change it to {{menu.getItemQuantity(category.items[$index])}} > 0. This will return true. If something is added, it will show because the number will go up. Make Sense?

Comment: if it is always true then it will always show. that is not the same as toggle behavior

Comment: @JudsonTerrell Did not work :(. but it does evaluate it once though.

Comment: Have you tried ng-if?

Comment: Also... try putting your function on $. getItemQuantity its highly recommended that everything be bound to the controller scope for things like this to function correctly.

Comment: @JudsonTerrell same thing

Comment: @JudsonTerrell what do you mean by '$.getItemQuantity' what does the dollar sign mean?

Comment: It is already bound to the controller scope. Look at the code above

Comment: So I have solved my own issue. I want to shoot myself in the face. Turns out that I should not use {{}} in ng-show

Comment: isn't he already calling that controller function in the show? `<span ng-show="{{menu.getItemQuantity(category.items[$index])}}">`  with `menu` referencing the controller?

Comment: lol glad you solved it! i should have totally caught that too. doh!

Comment: Was this a trick question? lol I've worked all day, didn't see that one either. Glad you got it solved

Answer (score 2):

I have solved my problem. It turns out that ng-show attribute takes in an expression and thus I should change

```
ng-show="{{expression}}"
```

to

```
ng-show="expression"
```